# Installing problems with Dell Vostro 3460

Tags: installation, hard-drive, raid, ssd

I'm having problems installing 12.04 or 11.04 in a new Dell Vostro 3460.

The issue becomes on the "Raid" performance that comes with the laptop, a 500GB HDD and a mini SATA 32GB SSD. With Windows there are no problems using this performance, the boot are in the SSD and the system loads very  fast, but when I try to install Ubuntu, it doesn't show any hard drive in the disk selection screen.

Does someone have or have solved this issue?

Comment: Anybody know anything about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I "solved" the problem running the Ubuntu as live CD (using a pen drive) and uninstalling the RAID (I really don't remender the specific command that I used). After that I was able to install Ubuntu, but every boot was showing a Intel blue screen asking to solve RAID issues (to make all drives as no RAID, ok I did that, no RAID, you won...). After  that a got ubuntu installed and no RAID at all.

I am wondering right now that am not using the 32GB cache and geting low performace... Dell was supposed to be Ubuntu certificated, but not for my new Vostro =(

Answer (score 1):

For remove RAID set:

`sudo dmraid -ay` # activate
`sudo dmraid -x`   # remove