# Restoring RAID after linux installation

Tags: 12.04, raid, ssd

After Years using windows and wishing to enter the linux world, I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04. I have a Dell vostro 3460 with:

1. 500 GB HDD
2. 32 GB SSD mSATA (cache - not physical drive)

My former OS was Windows 7. When I changed it to linux ubuntu, during the installation, I encountered problems concerning my drives. Apparently because I had RAID between the drives linux installation didn't know how to handle this so according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164981/installing-problems-with-dell-vostro-3460) post i had to delete the RAID. This puts me in a very sad situation because I have an SSD drive without the ability to use it (although linux recognizes it as a separate drive during the installation and lets me install linux on it, because its not a physical drive - I can't set it as a bootable hard drive).

So now I have a linux OS on my 500GB hard drive and an unusable SSD drive. Is it possible to "re-RAID" the drives or any other way to make the SSD usable again and still use ubuntu?


Because im a noobie in linux (in general and ubuntu in particular) a detailed answer will be much appreciated :) 


Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I don't think you can use the SSD as cache again. It's a "fakeraid" anyway (all in software/drivers). I suggest to try out as laid out in this similar question: [How to boot Ubuntu from SSD drive which cannot be selected as boot device?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234111/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-ssd-drive-which-cannot-be-selected-as-boot-device) And just install Ubuntu on the 32 GB SSD (plenty of space!) and have some other mount points on the regular hard drive.

Comment: You might also want to follow: [How do I install and use flashcache/bcache to cache HDD to SSD?](http://askubuntu.com/q/252140/88802)

Comment: I'm suffering the same problem as yours, however I have not found the solution. Today I went into the Intel Rapid's Setup and selected the option "reset RAID0" (the only option enabled) but nothing happened, I had no access to the SSD to configure a new RAID, total waste of time. Like you I am looking for a solution to this problem, already posted this doubt on Dell's Comunity Forum but got no response yet. If something solid come, please send me an email, cause I probably will do the same.